# company proxy issue with chrome and google accounts

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, dns, proxy, microsoft-edge

exposition - i get this image along with this text:

> The webpage at https://accounts.google.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   [image: webpage is not available ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED]

in internet explorer and edge, google accounts work just fine, while
adding [`--no-proxy-server`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-proxy-server) to chrome make it work even there as well.

as far as i can tell, both IE and chrome are configured with the same windows 10 proxy, since browsing through their settings all of 'em lead to the same windows "internet options" with a proxy set in stone.

i still couldn't find any position from the company if they're doing this on purpose, or think of any reasoning why they would block google accounts in chrome only.

what could be the reason?

Comment: Looks a lot like you are using specific proxy settings in Chrome. If you open settings in Chrome, Show advanced at bottom and click proxy settings, does it have any specific configurations for Chrome?

Comment: `tunnel` is specific to https, do you have this issue with any https website? Could it be that they try to inspect https traffic? How does e.g. Firefox behave? Do you have any more details about e.g. which proxy software is employed by your company? On a different note, maybe the guys at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) can better help you.

Comment: @Cown it only have an option to "open proxy settings" which leads to window's "internet properties".

Comment: @simlev this is only with accounts google as far as i could stumble upon. i've got no firefox, no authorization to install chrome extensions or any other thing. no idea which proxy company's using. this might have to do with data protection, so they probably wouldn't be inspecting data, much to the opposite. perhaps servervault indeed, nice hint! i'll check there later if this stays on zero and i still can't get a feedback inside. ;)